# Provider Hosted App unable to access List Item value from host web in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin, list-item, provider-hosted-app

I have a List on my host web in sharepoint by name 'PremiumCalculatorContent' which has two columns 'Title' and 'FriendlyName' and some data. I was trying to fetch these two column values from the List in Visual Studio (AppWeb project) using the below code, however it works for 'Title' but not for 'FriendlyName' column, it throws exception saying

> "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

Basically, I need to read all the columns and column values from the List.

I have been stuck with this issue. Probably I am missing something here, appreciate your help!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // The following code gets the client context and Title property by using TokenHelper.
            // To access other properties, the app may need to request permissions on the host web.
            var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);

            using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
            {
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.Title);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                //Response.Write(clientContext.Web.Title);

                ListCollection lists = clientContext.Web.Lists;
                List list = lists.GetByTitle("PremiumCalculatorContent");               

                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
                clientContext.Load<ListCollection>(lists);
                clientContext.Load<List>(list);
                clientContext.Load<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection>(items);

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in items)
                {
                    //Response.Write("<br />" + item.FieldValues["Title"]);
                    Response.Write("<br />" + item.FieldValues["FriendlyName"]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try This Code It May be Help You

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313688/read-items-from-list-in-host-web-from-provider-hosted-app

Answer (score 2):

The XML needs to include the list of columns to retrieve.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms442073%28v=office.15%29.aspx

```
<ViewFields>
  <FieldRef Name="Title"></FieldRef>
  <FieldRef Name="FriendlyName"></FieldRef>
</ViewFields>
```

Comment: I know in the JSOM, the ViewFields property of the CAML Query is effectively ignored... you have to put which fields you want in an argument to the load method. Is that not how managed CSOM works?

Answer (score 0):

If your list is ExternalList and you are trying to query list items via SP.CamlQuery and Sharepoint returns error "**The given key was not present in the dictionary**" then you have to specify all fields in the ViewFields collection (in SP.CamlQuery).

Please see [this blog](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2011/08/given-key-was-not-present-in-dictionary.html) for more details.